# How do I call the same activity with intent and pass values to it?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view, int pos) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YoutubePlayer.this , YoutubePlayer.class);
        String msg = recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchURL();
        String videoId = Uri.parse(msg).getQueryParameter("v");
        String videoChannel = recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchChannel();
        String videoTitle = recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchTitle();


        intent.putExtra("videoURL" , videoId);
        intent.putExtra("videoChannel" , videoChannel);
        intent.putExtra("videoTitle" , videoTitle);
        int i = pos ;
        singleList.add(new HorizontalModel(recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchTitle(), recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchURL(), recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchChannel()));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Toasting channel : " + videoChannel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

        String videoURL = intent.getStringExtra("videoURL");
        String videoTitle = intent.getStringExtra("videoTitle");
        String videoChannel = intent.getStringExtra("videoChannel");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video channel is  : " + videoChannel + "title : " + videoTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So here , when I pass putExtra values through the intent, and receive it , the values do not get passes and the variables just get assigned NULL values. But , the line
`singleList.add(new HorizontalModel(recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchTitle(), recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchURL(), recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchChannel()));`
works. So I assume it's not a problem in passing values but the system not taking the intents??

There were some questions posted earlier related to this topic here. They basically all said the same thing (which is something I was already using) -
`Intent intent = new Intent(YoutubePlayer.this , YoutubePlayer.class);` .
Some of the suggestions were also to add a `finish()` after calling the startActivity or `recreate()` both of which did not get the desired output.

Edit : Here's the entire code for the YoutubePlayer class

```
package com.dhanush.testingyoutube;

import static com.dhanush.testingyoutube.MySingleton.doubleList;
import static com.dhanush.testingyoutube.MySingleton.singleList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class YoutubePlayer extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemClickListener{

    TextView playerTitle ;
    TextView playerChannel ;
    TextView playerDescription ;
    TextView playerSubscriptions ;

    SearchActivity searchActivity ;
    ImageView playerMini ;
    RecyclerView recyclerView ;

    public ArrayList<SearchModel> recommendationList ;

    public SearchAdapter searchAdapter ;

    VideoModel[] listData ;

    ImageView videoLiked ;
    ImageView videoDisliked ;

    int i ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_player);

        playerDescription = findViewById(R.id.playerChannel);
        playerTitle = findViewById(R.id.playerTitle);
        playerMini = findViewById(R.id.playerMini);
        playerChannel = findViewById(R.id.playerSubs);
        playerSubscriptions = findViewById(R.id.playerSubscriptions);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recommendationRecycler);
        videoLiked = findViewById(R.id.videoLiked);
        videoDisliked = findViewById(R.id.videoDisliked);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String videoURL = intent.getStringExtra("videoURL");
        String videoTitle = intent.getStringExtra("videoTitle");
        String videoChannel = intent.getStringExtra("videoChannel");
        String finalVideo = videoChannel ;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video channel is  : " + videoChannel + "title : " + videoTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(videoChannel == null) {
            videoChannel = "Jet Lag   1.2M views   5 months ago";
        }
        String[] temp = videoChannel.split("   ") ;
        String ansChannel = "" ;
        String ansViews = "" ;
        int check = 0 ;

        recommendationList = new ArrayList<>();

        listData = new VideoModel[] {
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6k1Y35SJrY", "How the World’s 4 Cryogenics Companies Actually Work", R.drawable.halfasinteresting, "Half As Interesting   159K views   8 hours ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwJY54vONjE&t=5s", "Here’s Why I Love the 2000 Mercedes-Benz E55 AMG", R.drawable.doug, "Doug DeMuro   156K views   10 hours ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrAofachljM", "How to Embarrass a Thief", R.drawable.dailydose, "Daily Dose of Internet   2M views   10 hours ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmBRWyZJ4p4", "I Actually Bought 100 Scam Ads", R.drawable.ryan, "Ryan Trahan   1.8M views   12 hours ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bgNm9l_3qU", "How To Get Venom From The World's Deadliest Spider", R.drawable.veritasium, "Veritasium   906K views   1 day ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_FD452OphQ", "The STRANGEST ATV Concept", R.drawable.colin, "colinfurze   545K views   1 day ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHvusXgmc8I", "The Building Blocks Of An F1 Car! | Tech Talk | Crypto.com", R.drawable.f1, "FORMULA 1   57K views   1 day ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOs0yfwbTDE", "My Thoughts on The Google Pixel Tablet", R.drawable.dave, "Dave2D   324K views   2 days ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wyibBpZLcQ", "Building the World’s Fastest Walmart Motorcycle (Day 2)", R.drawable.donut, "Donut   1M views   1 day ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIo-j6Jv4UA&t=210s", "THIS IS BATTLEBIT", R.drawable.macro, "Macro LIVE   17K views   1 day ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I79TpDe3t2g&t=64s" , "The Cold War - OverSimplified (Part 1)" , R.drawable.oversimplified , "Oversimplifed   58M views   4 years ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmQ4Dqxs0HI" , "AI learns to play JUMP KING" , R.drawable.codebullet , "Code Bullet   7.1M views  1 year ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIYPuzWCCSw" , "Race Highlights | 2022 Bahrain Grand Prix" , R.drawable.f1 , "FORMULA 1   11M views   1 year ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0ejkkFT3V0" , "We Raced To Visit The Most US States In 100 Hours" , R.drawable.jetlag , "Jet Lag: The Game   1.2M views   6 months ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W72cyc5sESo&t=1977s" , "The History of Lego Star Wars World Records" , R.drawable.salt ,  "Summoning Salt   3.2M views   6 months ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHuFizITMdA" , "Turning cotton balls into cotton candy" , R.drawable.nile , "NileRed   11M views   1 year ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySLHgsln8_s" , "The Lamborghini Huracan Sterrato Is Pure Insanity" , R.drawable.doug , "Doug DeMuro   1M views   1 month ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFvXuyITwBI" , "Apple Vision Pro Impressions!" , R.drawable.marq , "Marques Brownlee   16M views   2 weeks ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9DyHthJ6LA" , "Gordon Ramsay Savagely Critiques Spicy Wings | Hot Ones" , R.drawable.feast , "First We Feast   118M views   4 years ago"),
                new VideoModel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbUjuwhQPKs" , "The Search For D. B. Cooper" , R.drawable.lemmino , "LEMMiNO   14M views   3 years ago")
        };

        Random random = new Random();

        ansChannel = ansChannel + ansViews ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < random.nextInt(10)+2 ; i++) {
            int t = random.nextInt(20);
            recommendationList.add(new SearchModel(listData[t].getVideoURL() , listData[t].getVideoTitle() , listData[t].getChannelImg() , listData[t].getChannelName()));
        }


        for(String arr : temp) {
            if(!(Character.isDigit(arr.charAt(0))) && check == 0) {
                ansChannel = ansChannel + "   " + arr ;
            }
            else {
                check = 1 ;
            }
            if(check == 1) {
                ansViews = ansViews + "   " +  arr ;
            }
        }
        int videoImg = intent.getIntExtra("videoMini" , 0);

        playerMini.setImageResource(videoImg);
        playerTitle.setText(videoTitle);
        playerChannel.setText(ansChannel);
        playerDescription.setText(ansViews);

        searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(searchActivity , recommendationList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this , LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL , false);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

        searchAdapter.setClickListener(this);

        int min = 1000000;
        int max = 15000000;
        int subs = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);

        String subscriptions = formatNumber(subs);

        playerSubscriptions.setText(subscriptions);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);

        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoURL, 0);
                youTubePlayer.play();
            }
        });

        String finalVideoChannel = videoChannel;
        String finalAnsChannel = ansChannel;
        videoLiked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(YoutubePlayer.this, "in liked clicker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                doubleList.add(new HorizontalModel(videoTitle , videoURL , finalAnsChannel));
            }
        });

    }
        public static String formatNumber(long number) {
            String[] suffix = new String[]{"", "K", "M", "B", "T"};
            int index = 0;
            double formattedNumber = number;

            while (formattedNumber >= 1000 && index < suffix.length - 1) {
                formattedNumber /= 1000;
                index++;
            }

            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
            return decimalFormat.format(formattedNumber) + " " + suffix[index] + " subscribers";
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int pos) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YoutubePlayer.this , YoutubePlayer.class);
        String msg = recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchURL();
        String videoId = Uri.parse(msg).getQueryParameter("v");
        String videoChannel = recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchChannel();
        String videoTitle = recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchTitle();


        intent.putExtra("videoURL" , videoId);
        intent.putExtra("videoChannel" , videoChannel);
        intent.putExtra("videoTitle" , videoTitle);
        i = pos ;
        singleList.add(new HorizontalModel(recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchTitle(), recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchURL(), recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchChannel()));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Toasting channel : " + videoChannel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: You're starting a duplicate Activity of the same Activity class, YoutubePlayer? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just learning app development right now, so just to test how much i've learnt , I was trying to make what is essentially a copy of YouTube. So this code here is part of the Youtube Player class where the video plays. There's recommendations beneath the video which on clicked , play the video. So i'm essentially only updating the values of the videoXXX variables. Which is what i was trying to do........ is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: No, that's fine. There would be a stack of the same type of Activity in the task stack, so when you press back, it goes back to the previous video you were looking at. I can't see any problems with your code. Maybe you need to show more of the surrounding code for us to be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: There isn't really much else in this class. It's just get the intented values , get/set the Image/Text views , then the YoutubePlayerView and finally the OnClick code. The only problem i can see is Intent not passing values.  I had to do some operations on the videoChannel variable so as it'd pass a null value , those wouldn't work , thowing a error and stopping the app in the emulator. So i assigned a dummy/test videoChannel value manually and Toasted the variables. All the variables that "getExtra" , where assigned null values

Comment: The code you’re showing is correct so you need to show more of the surrounding code for us to identify the issue.

Comment: kk , edited the post to add the entire code

Answer (score 0):

if you want data from Adapter(RecyclerView) then you should use Interface not Intent for same Activity like this

```
interface recommendationList {
    
    
        fun getSearchChannel(channelname: String)
    
}
```

in OnClick

```
recommendationList.getSearchChannel(recommendationList.get(pos).getSearchChannel())
```

in your activity add this

```
 override fun getSearchChannel(channelname: String) {

       
         videoChannel: String = channelname
// you can also make this global 
    }
```

don't forgot to import the interface at your activity